# Firebase Functions Typescript initializeAdmin() with specific uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have found reference to this method of initializing firebase functions with a unique UID for the purpose of constraining it with database rules, but I keep getting the error
`Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL`

I realize that I can retrieve the DatabaseURL from environment variables, but before I do that, I want to know if I'm doing something wrong because the examples I have seen have not had to do that for Firebase Functions.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp({
  ...functions.config().firebase,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: { uid: "functions" }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`functions.config().firebase` is deprecated.  Instead, you can build upon the contents of `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` instead.  Something like this (untested):

```
const config = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
config.databaseAuthVariableOverride = { uid: "uid" }
admin.initializeApp(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone interested in typescript version, the code needs to be updated with:

```
const config = JSON.parse(<string>process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG))
```