# Accessing Firebase admin from google cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access and update my firebase database from GOOGLE cloud function but it is not working.

I have written a cloud function in which I have **initialized firebase-admin.**

I have to provide **service_account** to initialize admin.

I am `initializing` my firebase app as

```
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(service_account),
  databaseURL: "",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: ""
  }
});
```

I don't have my service account path in GOOGLE cloud functions.

Is there any method to access firebase from GOOGLE cloud functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within Google Cloud Functions the required configuration data can be looked up automatically, so you don't have to provide configuration data for the Firebase Admin SDK.

All that is needed in most cases is:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
```

Also see the documentation section [Import the required modules and initialize an app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app).

Comment: But how can I pass `databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: ""
  }` in initializeApp()? If I pass like this it will give me error for not initializing a databaseURL value.

Comment: From the docs and [Doug's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959389/firebase-functions-typescript-initializeadmin-with-specific-uid), it seems you should be able to initialize with `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`.